# Why Glassfish 4 loses web socket messages?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, glassfish-4

I try to use web socket for messages (Glassfish 4 implementation). When I use `session.getBasicRemote().sendText` it works correctly but if I use `session.getAsyncRemote().sendText` some messages are lost. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText("{id: " + envelope.id + ", message: \"dddd\"}");
}
```

But the client receive around 190-195 messages.

Comment: How does your client/test look like? Maybe your client closes before all messages have been received.

Comment: Client is chrome, code: ws.onmessage = function(e) { i++; }

Comment: can you please try with latest nightly GF build? (http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.0.1/nightly/glassfish-4.0.1-b05-04_19_2014-ml.zip)